# kxml for parsing data from website

Tags: xml, parsing, java-me, midp, kxml

I am currently trying to develop an application using netbeans 6.9.1, but when I try to run the program I am getting the following error

```
Uncaught exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at javax.microedition.io.Connector.openPrim(), bci=31
    at javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(), bci=3
    at javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(), bci=3
    at javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(), bci=2
    at RSSParser$1.run(RSSParser.java:32)
```

this error is coming from this code

```
public void parse(final String url) {
Thread t = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    // set up the network connection
    HttpConnection hc = null;

    try {
      hc = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
      parse(hc.openInputStream());
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
      mRSSListener.exception(ioe);
    }
    finally {
      try { if (hc != null) hc.close(); }
      catch (IOException ignored) {}
    }
  }
};
t.start();
}
```

This method is being called from another class here

```
public void startApp() {
if (mDisplay == null)
  mDisplay = Display.getDisplay(this);

if (mInitialized == false) {
  // Put up the waiting screen.
  Screen waitScreen = new Form("Connecting...");
  mDisplay.setCurrent(waitScreen);
  // Create the title list.
  mTitleList = new List("Headlines", List.IMPLICIT);
  mExitCommand = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 0);
  mDetailsCommand = new Command("Details", Command.SCREEN, 0);
  mTitleList.addCommand(mExitCommand);
  mTitleList.addCommand(mDetailsCommand);
  mTitleList.setCommandListener(this);
  // Start parsing.
  String url = getAppProperty("RSSMIDlet.URL");
  RSSParser parser = new RSSParser();
  parser.setRSSListener(this);
  parser.parse(url);
  mInitialized = true;
}
else
  mDisplay.setCurrent(mTitleList);
}
```

When I debug it, it is saying the "String url" is null, how do I solve this?

I have also put a url in the string url like so:

```
String url = getAppProperty("RSSMIDlet.http://wwww.anything.com");
String url = getAppProperty("http://wwww.anything.com");
```

but this shouldn't matter as the first way has a default url to go to.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
String url = "http://wwww.anything.com";
```

If you refer to the article [Parsing XML in J2ME](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/parsingxml/), you should be aware it is from 2002 and kxml has advanced since then.

If you are in the unfortunate situation to get the midlet running, this [documentation](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/getAppProperty/) may be of interest you. IMHO, you need to configure the midlet by setting the property name *RSSMIDlet.URL* to *http://wwww.anything.com* in the manifest file.

Comment: but how do you set the property name of RSSMIDlet.URL to the url?

Comment: The article "Retrieving MIDlet Attributes" (second link) should help you in detail. It states: [...] The JAR file contains a manifest, /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, a special file that contains metainformation [...] such as attributes for both AMS and MIDlet.